# How to make two AJAX calls for two different stores in ExtJS?

Tags: extjs, proxy, extjs4

I want two stores for generating two charts in same window. Both get JSON data from the server.

```
Ext.regModel('chartdata', 
{
    fields: [{ name: 'x', type: 'string' },
             { name: 'a', type: 'float' },
             { name: 'b', type: 'float' },
             { name: 'c', type: 'float' },
             { name: 'd', type: 'int' },
             'Year'
            ]
});

var store = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: 'chartdata',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'here is my url'

    }
});

Ext.regModel('authTaskWiseData', {
    fields: ['state_name', 'state_code', 'Basic_Literacy', 'Continuing_Education', 'Equivalency', 'Training', 'Community_Mobisilation', 'Management']

});

var authStore = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: 'authTaskWiseData',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'second url'
    }
});

store.load();
authStore.load();
```

Only the first AJAX call is actually sent, but not the second.  What might be the problem?

Comment: The code looks ok. If the first store works, then the 2nd should work also. Check again.

Answer (score 0):

Trying adding autoload:true to your store declaration if you need them to load immediately.